# How to find the Effective end Date for the below table using select statement only

Tags: sql

How to find the Effective end Date for the below table using select statement only

This is the actual table:

```
EMID ENAME DEPT_NO  EFDT
101 ANUJ    10  1/1/2018
101 ANUJ    11  1/1/2020
101 ANUJ    12  5/1/2020
102 KUNAL   12  1/1/2019
102 KUNAL   14  1/1/2020
102 KUNAL   15  5/1/2020
103 AJAY    11  1/1/2018
103 AJAY    12  1/1/2020
104 RAJAT   10  1/1/2018
104 RAJAT   12  1/1/2020
```

This is desired output:

```
EMID ENAME DEPTNO    EFDT     EF_ENDT
101 ANUJ    10  1/1/2018    12/31/2019
101 ANUJ    11  1/1/2020    4/30/2020
101 ANUJ    12  5/1/2020    NULL
102 KUNAL   12  1/1/2019    12/31/2019
102 KUNAL   14  1/1/2020    4/30/2020
102 KUNAL   15  5/1/2020    NULL
103 AJAY    11  1/1/2018    12/31/2019
103 AJAY    12  1/1/2020    NULL
104 RAJAT   10  1/1/2018    12/31/2019
104 RAJAT   12  1/1/2020    NULL
```

The EF_ENDT needs to be populated using the statement only.

How can we do this?

This code can be generic for all Database

Comment: *Why* did you tag MySQL, and the T-SQL (which is used by SQL Server and the very old SyBase RDBMS) and PL\SQL (used by Oracle) dialects, and then tag Sybase? At least learn what RDBMS and dialect you're using. Tagging multiple RDBMS (4 here) will just get your question ignored by the users here; it will give the opposite effect to what you want. What were *your* attempts? Why didn't they work? Please [edit] your qusetion to adress the tags I've removed (retag the correct RDBMS), include your attempts (and tell us why they didn't work) and explain the logic for your expected results.

Comment: We can't see  your database, so we have no idea how those end dates are determined. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want a lead and then to subtract one day.  The standard SQL for this is:

```
select t.*,
       lead(efdt) over (partition by emid order by efdt) - interval '1 day' as ef_enddt
from t;
```

Date/time function vary significantly among databases.  All provide some method for subtracting one day.  You'll probably have to adapt this to your particular (unstated) database.